# Xview3 reference model leads to Loss in NaN stopping training

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, resnet

As a challenge I took on refreshing the Xview3 Reference Model found here:

[https://github.com/DIUx-xView/xview3-reference](https://%20https://github.com/DIUx-xView/xview3-reference)

This is an AI/ML model to look at Synthetic Aperture Radar (SAR) images for illegal fishing vessels.

It runs in a Jupyter Notebook which makes trouble shooting easier.

After fixing some minor module warnings and updating some of the models I ran into a Loss NaN error in the training step and cannot seem to resolve it.

**Optimizer and training parameters**

We use a standard stochastic gradient descent optimizer for the Faster R-CNN model. Feel free to play around with more advanced optimizers such as Adam, RMSProp, or others.

Additionally, we use a step-based learning rate scheduler to decay the learning rate over the duration of the training. You could experiment with other LR schedules. For the reference implementation, we've kept this straightforward.

```
# construct an optimizer
params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.0075,
                            momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
# and a learning rate scheduler
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                                step_size=3,
                                                gamma=0.1)

# let's train it for N epochs
num_epochs = 3
```

**Train the model**

Here is where it goes a foul the training the model is done via torchvision's provided train_one_epoch function which wraps the traditional PyTorch training loop into an easy-to-use function made for built-in object detectors. The model is saved every epoch.

```
# Train the model for three epochs
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # train for one epoch, printing every iteration
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader_train, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
    # Check for NaN in loss
    if torch.isnan(loss).any():
        raise ValueError(f'Loss is NaN at epoch {epoch}')
    # update the learning rate
    lr_scheduler.step()
    # evaluate on the test dataset
    evaluate(model, data_loader_val, device=device)

    checkpoint_path = f'trained_model_{epoch+1}_epochs.pth'
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), checkpoint_path)
```

And here is the error:

```
Epoch: [0]  [ 0/65]  eta: 0:01:53  lr: 0.000125  loss: 2.8789 (2.8789)  loss_classifier: 1.2008 (1.2008)  loss_box_reg: 0.0105 (0.0105)  loss_objectness: 1.5033 (1.5033)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1643 (0.1643)  time: 1.7462  data: 0.4061  max mem: 5038
Loss is nan, stopping training
{'loss_classifier': tensor(1.2711, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>), 'loss_box_reg': tensor(0.0248, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>), 'loss_objectness': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward0>), 'loss_rpn_box_reg': tensor(0.1041, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)}

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1


/home/q/anaconda3/envs/xview3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3556: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

I have tried changing the optimizer to ADAM and adjusting the loss rate to no success.